# Should I have only one GRUB on Dual boot Linux system?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a fresh system where Ubuntu and Kali is installed. This system has two swaps for each but both Linux-es are using two swaps.

I saw that when I updated Ubuntu then Ubuntu came first in grub list.

Should I have only one GRUB? Benefits and drawback?

How to remove one grub, if I should have one Grub for both Linux-es?

I want to experiment with Kali and use Ubuntu as regular OS.

Comment: Can you try explaining it again? What does swap have to do with your Grub question. What do you mean two grubs?

Comment: Please edit your original question with the new explanation.

Comment: Swaps may not be related. Just thought, if it is.

Comment: You can, but you don't have to. The choice is yours. There are no big drawbacks or benefits.